# Running SikuliX 1.1.4 Python scripts from Command Line

Tags: python, jython, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-x

I have some Python (`jython` actually) scripts that run with Sikulix.

I was previously using version **1.1.1** and was using the command line (after doinmg the setup):

```
java -Dsikuli.Debug=-2 -cp sikulix.jar org.python.util.jython main.py
```

With version **1.1.4**, there is no more setup, and `jython` has been removed from *sikulix.jar* and *sikulixapi.jar*. Jython is in another jar file (*jython-standalone-2.7.1.jar*).

I tried to run with following command line

```
java -Dsikuli.Debug=-2 -cp "sikulix.jar;jython-standalone-2.7.1.jar" org.python.util.jython main.py
```

But I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sikuli.Sikuli import *
ImportError: No module named sikuli
```

The documentation is not fully updated on how to do it. They mention installation of `jython`, `jip` and other stuff but nothing managed to work.

Any idea on how to do it?

Thanks

**==PS==**:

After doing the following it almost worked:

- Installing `jython`
- Setting `CLASSPATH` to absolute path of *sikulixapi.jar*
- Running `jython main.py`

I got the following error:

```
[error] RunTimeINIT:  *** terminating: Java arch not 64 Bit or not detected (java 8-32 version 1.8 vm 25.121-b13 class 52.0 arch null)
```

I have installed Jython with a 32-bits Java and it seems 64-bits Java is required.

I will probably try again with 64-bits Java JDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line at the beginning of your script

```
import org.sikuli.script.SikulixForJython
```

This will help to look for `sikuli` module in Java classes.

You can then run with the command line mentionned previously:

```
java -cp "sikulixapi.jar;jython-standalone-2.7.1.jar" org.python.util.jython main.py
```

---

*Example of Python script (main.py)*:

```
import org.sikuli.script.SikulixForJython
from sikuli.Sikuli import *

notepad = App('notepad.exe')
notepad.open()
sleep(1)
type("It is working!")
notepad.close()
```

Comment: should notepad be launched and shown on the screen? (I have 3 monitors with win10, not sure if that is causing a constraint)

Comment: @ffejrekaburb yes it should show, and no 3 monitors should not be an issue (I have the same config in my office).